# Ignore prefixed numbers in expression

Tags: regex

I'm attempting to exclude a set of matches that have a prefix in front of them. Here's my example set:

`752 7461041 2032083GF-1620 853069-46`

The result should be:

`752 7461041 2032083 853069`

Notice that prefix `GF-` and `-` were both ignored.

My current working expression is `([\d]+)` which ends up including 46 and 1620. I know how to exclude values but with the `?!` syntax but combining it into the expression throws me off.

I tried `((?!-)([\d]+))` but I suppose I'm getting the grouping wrong.

Comment: If you extract, try a whitespace boundary: `(?<!\S)\d+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use a lookahead here.

You can search using this regex:

```bash
\b(\d+)\S*
```

and replace it with `$1`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/I0mIfd/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(\d+)`: Match 1+ digits in capture group #1
- `\S+`: Match 0 or more non-whitespaces to match remaining characters

Comment: Hmmmm that didn't work perfectly unfortunately. The result is 75 746104 2032083 853069, the first and second numbers are missing a digits. ie 752 and 7461041

Comment: Sorry it was a silly mistake. I have fixed it now. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a regex pattern which will *match* the non prefixed numbers, you could try:

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?=(?:GF)?-|\s|$)
```

This says to match:

- `(?<!\S)` assert that what precedes is either whitepace or the start of the string
- `\d+` match an integer number
- `(?=` lookahead and assert

  - `(?:GF)?` optional `GF` prefix
  - `-` hyphen
  - `|` OR
  - `\s` any whitespace character
  - `|` OR
  - `$` the end of the string
- `)` end lookahead

Here is a working [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VvujBb/1).